# Duplicated in Pandas : how does it work?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry but I truly don't understand the output of the code :

```
json_string = '''{"x":{"a":585,"b":585,"c":586,"d":586},
   "y":{"a":"EC","b":"SA","c":"EF","d":"CA"},
   "z":{"a":28,"b":14,"c":28,"d":7}}'''

df = pd.read_json(json_string)
print(df)
print(df.duplicated(keep = False))
```

This leads me to :

```
     x   y   z
a  585  EC  28
b  585  SA  14
c  586  EF  28
d  586  CA   7

a     True
b    False
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool
```

Can someone please explain why "585  EC  28" is equal to "586  CA   7" ?
Is this a bug in Pandas ? Should I go on github with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, which version of pandas are you on?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I run pandas 0.17.0. I'm upgrading to 0.18.0rc1 and reach you back.

Comment: Nice ! It perfectly works on 0.18.0rc1. I'm really sorry for the false flag, I should have upgraded my Pandas first. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, the bug is resolved in 0.18.0rc1. (Thanks Fabio Lamanna)
Please upgrade your Pandas if you encounter a similar issue !